# Importing a CSV in MySQL. Only every second line is imported

Tags: mysql, csv, import

i want to import a csv table into mysql with this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/SA01505.csv' INTO TABLE hks.orc CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLUMNS  TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var1,@var2,@var3,`TI 41-40`,`TI 41-41`,`TI 41-42`,`TI42-40`,`TI 42-41`,`TI 42-42`,`TI 42-43`,`TI 42-43.2`,`TI 42-44`,`TI 42-45`,`TI 42-46`,`TI 42-47`,`PI 42-71`,`PI 42-72`,`PI 42-73`,`PI 42-75`,`FI 42-90`,`TI 43-40`,`TI 43-41`,`TI 45-40`,`TI 45-41`,`TI 47-41`,`TI 47-42`,`TI 47-43`,`TI 47-44`,`LI 42-61`,`SI 44-81`,`QI 46-22`,`UV 41-10_Soll`,`UV 41-10_Ist`,`UV43-10_Soll`,`UV43-10_Ist`,`Tc2`,`Tc3`,`Tc4`) 
SET Datum = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var2,@var3),'%Y/%m/%d%k:%i:%s');
```

This code works, but imports only every second line, although every line is terminated with "\n" (i checked this with an hex-editor)

Comment: that could be a nice question if there was a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the problem is here: `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  ESCAPED BY '"'`. This is biting each other.

In the first line imported the last `"` of the enclosed column escapes the `\n` of the line terminator. Therefore always two lines are treated as one and you probably don't see the "second line" in the imported data because the data gets truncated.

Remove the `ESCAPED BY '"'` clause and see if it works. If it works but you need it to properly import your data, you'll have to work on your data.